# 2 ListBox on one userform, select next index

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 listboxes on one userform. On Clicking a command button, I want select the next item using "ListIndex+1". It work nicely for one listbox2 but I could not do the same with ListBox3. However when I remove the codes for Listbox3 then it works well for Listbox2 alone.

```
With UserForm1.ListBox2
    If UserForm1.ListBox2.ListIndex = UserForm1.ListBox2.ListCount - 1 Then
        UserForm1.ListBox2.ListIndex = 0
    Else
        UserForm1.ListBox2.ListIndex = UserForm1.ListBox2.ListIndex + 1
    End If
End With

With UserForm1.ListBox3
    If UserForm1.ListBox3.ListIndex = UserForm1.ListBox3.ListCount - 1 Then
        UserForm1.ListBox3.ListIndex = 0
    Else
        UserForm1.ListBox3.ListIndex = UserForm1.ListBox3.ListIndex + 1
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Your code appears to work - tested it with five items in each listbox.  When I clicked the command button (containing your code) the selected item in each listbox moved down one.  One change I'd make is that within the `With` blocks you don't need to fully qualify the list reference - `If .ListIndex = .ListCount-1 Then` and `.ListIndex = 0` will work.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My problem is that the code does not work for Listbox3. It worked good only for Listbox2.

Comment: This works With UserForm1.ListBox2
If .ListIndex = .ListCount - 1 Then
.ListIndex = 0
Else
.ListIndex = .ListIndex + 1
End If
End With

Comment: This will not work:- With UserForm1.ListBox2
If .ListIndex = .ListCount - 1 Then
.ListIndex = 0
Else
.ListIndex = .ListIndex + 1
End If
End With

With UserForm1.ListBox3
If .ListIndex = .ListCount - 1 Then
.ListIndex = 0
Else
.ListIndex = .ListIndex + 1
End If
End With

Comment: How does it not work? Does it give a message?  Is the control definitely called `Listbox3`?

Comment: With Listbox2 , the codes work fine. When added similar codes for ListBox3 then Listbox2 index nothing selected while Listbox3 index goes to index 0. No error message.